# Transform answer of REST API

Tags: sql, json, database, sqlite

I tried to create a database using sqlite3 and ES6. To receive the data of the database I created REST methods.
When I use GET on the API I receive this answer for example:

```
{
    "user": [
        {
            value1: tmp,
            value2: test,

        }
    ]
}
```

But I need the answer to be simple JSON, it should be like this

```
{
    "user": {
        value1: tmp,
        value2: test,

    }
}
```

The code I used for the GET method is:

```
// GET the user
app.get("/api/userTemplate", (req, res, next) => {
    var sql = "select * from user"
    var params = []
    db.all(sql, params, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(400).json({"error":err.message});
            return;
        }
        res.json({
            "user":rows
        })
    });
});
```

I am aware this will return the full table of users, this is intended.

EDIT: `"user":rows[0]` works for me, but this returns only one row of the table. Is it possible to modify this in order to return all rows of the table?

Comment: `{ user: rows[0] }`?